# Display video instead of product thumbnail on WooCommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to display video of a WooCommerce product on shop page using Advanced Custom Fields plugin .

I want to create a condition, if a product has a video, then show it instead of `woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail`.

```php
$file = get_field('archive_video'); if( $file ) { ?> 
<video width="200" muted loop autoplay src="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>"></video> <?php
} else {
  /** 
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10;
   */
}
```

---

Am I choosing the correct approach?

Here how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following way using hooks instead of overriding template:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 9 );
function action_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    global $product;

    $file = get_field('archive_video', $product->get_id());

    if( isset($file['url']) && ! empty($file['url']) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

        echo '<video width="200" muted loop autoplay src="' . $file['url'] . '"></video>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: @Артем I have just added a missing ";"…

Comment: @Артем I just tested that on storefront theme and it works… So the issue is related to your theme customization or to a third party plugin…

Comment: can you tell me, where i can look for the issue? Cause I cant understand why its not working.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to display the thumbnail and when the user hovers or swipes in mobile, it plays a preview snippet of the video... like YouTube. Is this possible?